# Error in newly re-installed RStudio (Windows XP)

Tags: r, rstudio

What is the meaning of the following error when I start RStudio, and how can I address it? I re-installed a new version of R (3.2.1) and did a reinstall of RStudio

"rsession.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point strerror_s could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll."

Comment: Are you certain RStudio supports win xp? Their [download page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) only lists win vista, 7, and 8.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Rstudio with R(3.2.1) to my XP box and get this same error message when opening Rstudio.  Clicking "OK" and moving past the error message yields what appears to be a perfectly good Rstudio.  That is, I have used tutorials and it works as the tutorial indicates it should.  Plotting is fine, calculating is fine, etc.

Comment: I can confirm that clicking past the error does appears to work ok though you will get the error each time RStudio is started. Better is to install the official version for Windows XP (0.98.1103), for which see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can install a old version of Rstudio that was still supporting XP: For instance https://download1.rstudio.org/RStudio-0.98.245.exe

Comment: Link not working in Oct 2016 and old version anyway. The official RStudio link to older versions is given in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from RockScience points to an out-of-date URL (and older version of RStudio). This is the [official RStudio page for older versions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio), where version 0.98.1103  is available. This message was written in Oct 2016.

On installation the reported error does not occur and everything appears to work fine. However, the following appears in the Console:

```
Warning message:
R graphics engine version 11 is not supported by this version of RStudio.
The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

Not sure of the full meaning of this warning but all plot types that I tested so far seem to work great. They do appear in a separate window, however, and not integrated into the "Plots" tab of RStudio. After installing the "ggplot2" package, the warning still occurs.